# Перебор массива несколько раз и с заданных элементов

Tags: python, массивы

Круговой массив - массив из элементов, в котором по достижению конца массива следующим
элементом будет снова первый. Mассив задается числом n, то есть представляет собой числа от 1
до n.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример кругового массива для n=3:

Напишите программу, которая выводит путь, по которому, двигаясь интервалом длины m по
заданному массиву, концом будет являться первый элемент.

Началом одного интервала является конец предыдущего. Путь - массив из начальных элементов
полученных интервалов.

Пример 1:
n = 4, m = 3

Решение:
Круговой массив: 1234. При длине обхода 3 получаем интервалы: 123, 341.
Полученный путь: 13.

Пример 2:
n = 5, m = 4

Решение:
Круговой массив: 12345.
При длине обхода 4 получаем интервалы: 1234, 4512, 2345, 5123, 3451.

Полученный путь: 14253.

Параметры передаются в качестве аргументов командной строки.
Например, для последнего примера на вход подаются аргументы: 5 4

Ожидаемый вывод в консоль: 14253

Comment: Понятно, что вы бы хотели, но этот сайт не для решения задач за других. :-(